# Convert byte array to list<byte> using Silverlight and C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, list, arrays, type-conversion

How do I convert a `byte[]` array to a `list<byte>`?

I am using the Silverlight framework only.

Comment: var list = new List<byte>(bytes);   bytes are byte[]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply:

```
List<byte> myBytes = new List<Byte>(byteArray);
```

Or using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) extensions:

```
List<byte> myBytes = byteArray.ToList();
```